# Comparing characters in Rebol 3

Tags: unicode, character, rebol, rebol3, codepoint

I am trying to compare characters to see if they match.  I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  I'm expecting `true` on the output, but I'm getting false.

```
character: "a"
word: "aardvark"

(first word) = character ; expecting true, getting false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `"a"` in Rebol is not a character, it is actually a string.

A single unicode character is its own independent type, with its own literal syntax, e.g. `#"a"`.  For example, it can be converted back and forth from INTEGER! to get a [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point), which the single-letter string `"a"` cannot:

```
>> to integer! #"a"
== 97

>> to integer! "a"  
** Script error: cannot MAKE/TO integer! from: "a"
** Where: to
** Near: to integer! "a"
```

A string is not a series of one-character STRING!s, it's a series of CHAR!.  So what you want is therefore:

```
character: #"a"
word: "aardvark"

(first word) = character ;-- true!
```

---

*(Note: Interestingly, binary conversions of both a single character string and that character will be equivalent:*

```
>> to binary! "μ"
== #{CEBC}

>> to binary! #"μ"
== #{CEBC}
```

*...those are UTF-8 byte representations.)*

Comment: I personally think it would be helpful if, at least for the baseline `=` operator, if single character strings were treated equivalent to characters.  The stricter `==` might still return false.  These and other issues discussed in [the chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)

Comment: Be careful about using actions on string! datatypes.

>> pick "test" 2

== #"e"

Answer (score 4):

I recommend for cases like this, when things start to behave in a different way than you expected, to use things like `probe` and `type?`.  This will help you get a sense of what's going on, and you can use the interactive Rebol console on small pieces of code.

For instance:

```
>> character: "a"

>> word: "aardvark"

>> type? first word
== char!

>> type? character
== string!
```

So you can indeed see that the first element of `word` is a character #"a", while your `character` is the string! "a".  (Although I agree with @HostileFork that comparing a string of length 1 and a character is for a human the same.)

Other places you can test things are http://tryrebol.esperconsultancy.nl or in the chat room with [RebolBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/3960/rebolbot-a-chat-bot-for-the-chat-rooms)